# How to print a UTF-8 unicode string as EBCDIC in PL/I

Tags: mainframe, pl-i

How can I instruct PL/I to print a UTF-8 value as EBCDIC.  Is there a "trick" in PL/I or do I have to call the z/OS unicode services to convert the UTF-8 value?

```
PUT SKIP EDIT('VAR: ',VAR) (A,A);
```

Using the above instruction gives unreadable output.

```
VAR: &   (!¢
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [UTF8TOCHAR](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/epfz/6.1?topic=subroutines-utf8tochar), which appears to be new with IBM Enterprise PL/I version 5.

`PUT SKIP EDIT('VAR: ',UTF8TOCHAR(VAR)) (A,A);`

That's just freehand, but I think you get the idea.